# Check Service is running in background in kitkat

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

This code is working fine in all version but I have issue with KitKat

```
 private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) ToyotaFillActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {

        Log.e("@@@Text1:",serviceClass.getName()+"@@@TEST2:"+service.service.getClassName());
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            System.out.println("Already Running");

            return true;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("false");

    return false;
 }
```

**In kitkat this is return false**

Comment: others version is true?

Comment: yes other return true when the service is running but in kitkat the service is running but return false

Comment: please using getApplicationContext() instead of ToyotaFillActivity

Comment: yes I am already do!!

Comment: you dont need any method like `isMyServiceRunning`, what would you use it for?

Comment: I want to check that the service is running in background or not on behalf of running service I stop music and play music in background